# How can i automatically center the content of a pane while scaling the window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, resize, alignment, fxml

I have a little problem with my JavaFX project.
Here you have a screenshot of the UI:

[image: The UI]

When I scale the window it looks like this:

[image: The scaled UI]

I now want to center the content of the window, but the color of the menubar and the searchbar should be on the whole window, just as it is on the 2nd picture.

Here is the FXML code for the UI:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<StackPane prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ezmovie_prototype.controller_home">
   <children>
      <GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" prefWidth="1280.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="165.0" minHeight="165.0" prefHeight="165.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="735.0" minHeight="735.0" prefHeight="735.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="165.0" prefWidth="1280.0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="100.0" minHeight="100.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1080.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C60F25;" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="160.0" minWidth="160.0" percentWidth="0.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="920.0" minWidth="920.0" percentWidth="0.0" prefWidth="920.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="100.0" minHeight="100.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <TextField maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="920.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="760.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="920.0" promptText="Suche nach Film, Serien..." GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets top="30.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSuchen" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="160.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="160.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" text="Suchen" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="20.0" top="30.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button maxHeight="70.0" maxWidth="130.0" minHeight="70.0" minWidth="130.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Button" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/logo.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="1280.0" style="-fx-background-color: #585858;" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="90.0" prefWidth="90.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="580.0" minWidth="580.0" prefWidth="580.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnHome" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/home.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnFavoriten" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/favoriten.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnListen" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="0.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/list.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSerien" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/series.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnFilme" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/movies.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnLogout" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="0.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logout" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/logout.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSettings" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="0.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/settings.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <BorderPane prefHeight="715.0" prefWidth="1280.0" style="-fx-background-color: FFFFFF;" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <center>
                  <GridPane style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1280.0" minWidth="1280.0" prefWidth="1280.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="280.0" minHeight="280.0" prefHeight="280.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="280.0" minHeight="280.0" prefHeight="280.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <BorderPane prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="1130.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-border-radius: 10px;" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                           <opaqueInsets>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                           </opaqueInsets>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <center>
                              <GridPane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1200.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="1200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </GridPane>
                           </center>
                           <bottom>
                              <ScrollBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </ScrollBar>
                           </bottom>
                        </BorderPane>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Beliebte Filme" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Beliebte Filme" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                           </font>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </Text>
                        <BorderPane prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="1130.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-border-radius: 10px;" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <center>
                              <GridPane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1200.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="1200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </GridPane>
                           </center>
                           <bottom>
                              <ScrollBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </ScrollBar>
                           </bottom>
                        </BorderPane>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

I'm new to JavaFX, I need to program this for a school project.

Any advice appreciated, 
Thanks, Timo

edit: 
It should work like for example in css with this command:

```
margin: auto;
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Without testing it, I think the problem is the width property. I gave it a try and replaced some of the `maxWidth="1280.0"` with `maxWidth="9999.0"` (you should use the `Double` constant `MAX_VALUE` here!). Additionally keep in mind, that setting the `minWidth` property results in the UI not beeing able to be scaled less that this value. You should try to minimize the fixed setting of width and height properties, especially when you combine them (and having equal values for several like min, pref and max, is always fishy). Also always have a look at `hgrow` and `vgrow`, if applicable.

Comment: Where does your unhealthy obsession with `GridPane`s come from? Seriously there are `GridPane`s within `GridPane`s within `GridPane`s which is a good indicator for a flaw in your ui design. Also you often use `BorderPane`, where a simple `VBox` would be sufficient. Prefer simpler UI structures over complicated ones that achieve the same effect. Also move repeated parts to a different fxml file to remove the amount of code required. You can still access those elements with nested controllers, if necessary.

Comment: @fabian, I don't know, in school we learned about the 'GridPane' and the 'BorderPane'. I dont really know the differences from all the panes in FX.
For me it just was the easiest way to work with those panes, because i already knew them. 
But i see, i have to inform me a bit more about that!
Have you any advice for me?
Kind regards, Timo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that should be changed in your fxml:

- Don't use that many `GridPane`s. Think twice before putting a `GridPane` inside a `GridPane`. There are other layouts more suited for this purpose.
- You basically repeat the *Beliebte Filme* part twice, which not just increases the size of your fxml file, but if you need to change both of them, you need to edit 2 nodes. Use `<fx:include>` and nested controllers instead.
- You use absolute file paths to your images. This works on your PC, but once you submit your project, this most likely ceases to work. Put those images to the jar you submit and use urls relative to the fxml
- You need less duplication in the fxml file, if you use a css file to style the content.

Regarding the placement of the content: put it inside a `Group` (if it isn't already a single `Node`) and use `alignment="CENTER"` or `alignment="TOP_CENTER"`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="ezmovie_prototype.controller_home">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <top>
        <VBox fillWidth="true">
            <children>
                <HBox styleClass="search-bar">
                    <ImageView fitWidth="130" fitHeight="70" preserveRatio="true">
                        <Image url="@data/icons/logo.png" />
                    </ImageView>
                    <TextField maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="920.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="760.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="920.0" promptText="Suche nach Film, Serien..." VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" >
                        <font>
                            <Font size="20.0" />
                        </font>
                        <HBox.margin>
                            <Insets top="30.0" />
                        </HBox.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <Button fx:id="btnSuchen" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="160.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="160.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" text="Suchen">
                        <HBox.margin>
                            <Insets left="20.0" top="30.0" />
                        </HBox.margin>
                        <font>
                            <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                        </font>
                    </Button>
                </HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="tool-bar" maxHeight="80">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnHome" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Home">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@data/icons/home.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnFavoriten" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Favoriten">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@data/icons/favoriten.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnFilme" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Filme">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@data/icons/movies.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSerien" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Serien">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@data/icons/series.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnListen" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Listen">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@data/icons/list.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Region VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" prefWidth="9E10" prefHeight="1"></Region><!-- Just a empty placeholder for spacing -->
                        <Button fx:id="btnSettings" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Settings">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@data/icons/settings.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnLogout" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logout" text="Logout">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="30" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@data/icons/logout.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" fillWidth="false" >
            <children>
                <fx:include fx:id="film1" source="film.fxml" />
                <fx:include fx:id="film2" source="film.fxml" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

#### style.css

```css
.tool-bar {
    -fx-background-color: #585858;
}

.tool-bar > .button {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-content-display: top;
    -fx-max-width: 60;
    -fx-min-width: 60;
    -fx-max-height: 60;
    -fx-min-height: 60;
    -fx-shape: "M0,0H1V1H0Z";
}

.tool-bar > .button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #777;
}

.search-bar {
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
    -fx-background-color: #C60F25;
    -fx-max-height: 100;
    -fx-min-height: 100;
}

.search-bar > * {
    -fx-margin: 100;
}

.films > .content {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

#### film.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<VBox styleClass="films" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ezmovie_prototype.FilmController">
    <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Beliebte Filme">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
        </VBox.margin>
        <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
        </font>
    </Text>
    <BorderPane styleClass="content" prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="1130.0">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
        </VBox.margin>
        <center>
            <GridPane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1200.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="1200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </rowConstraints>
                <BorderPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                </BorderPane.margin>
            </GridPane>
        </center>
        <bottom>
            <ScrollBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <BorderPane.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                </BorderPane.margin>
            </ScrollBar>
        </bottom>
    </BorderPane>
</VBox>
```

#### Controller

```
@FXML
private FilmController film1Controller;
@FXML
private FilmController film2Controller;
```

Comment: Nice one, @fabian - I havn't found the time to further look into it, so it's great you stepped up!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `maxWidth="1280.0"` with `maxWidth="9999.0"` on every location in your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<StackPane prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ezmovie_prototype.controller_home">
   <children>
      <GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" prefWidth="1280.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="165.0" minHeight="165.0" prefHeight="165.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="735.0" minHeight="735.0" prefHeight="735.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="165.0" prefWidth="1280.0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="100.0" minHeight="100.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1080.0" style="-fx-background-color: #C60F25;" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="160.0" minWidth="160.0" percentWidth="0.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="920.0" minWidth="920.0" percentWidth="0.0" prefWidth="920.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="100.0" minHeight="100.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <TextField maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="920.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="760.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="920.0" promptText="Suche nach Film, Serien..." GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets top="30.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </TextField>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSuchen" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="160.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="160.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" text="Suchen" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="20.0" top="30.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button maxHeight="70.0" maxWidth="130.0" minHeight="70.0" minWidth="130.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Button" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/logo.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="1280.0" style="-fx-background-color: #585858;" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="90.0" prefWidth="90.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="580.0" minWidth="580.0" prefWidth="580.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnHome" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/home.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnFavoriten" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/favoriten.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnListen" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="0.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/list.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSerien" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/series.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnFilme" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/movies.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnLogout" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="0.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logout" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/logout.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSettings" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" maxHeight="0.0" maxWidth="60.0" minHeight="60.0" minWidth="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Home" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <effect>
                              <ImageInput>
                                 <source>
                                    <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/ezmovie_prototype/data/icons/settings.png" />
                                 </source>
                              </ImageInput>
                           </effect>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <BorderPane prefHeight="715.0" prefWidth="1280.0" style="-fx-background-color: FFFFFF;" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <center>
                  <GridPane style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="9999.0" minWidth="1280.0" prefWidth="1280.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="280.0" minHeight="280.0" prefHeight="280.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="65.0" minHeight="65.0" prefHeight="65.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="280.0" minHeight="280.0" prefHeight="280.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <BorderPane prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="1130.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-border-radius: 10px;" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                           <opaqueInsets>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                           </opaqueInsets>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <center>
                              <GridPane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1200.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="1200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </GridPane>
                           </center>
                           <bottom>
                              <ScrollBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </ScrollBar>
                           </bottom>
                        </BorderPane>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Beliebte Filme" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Beliebte Filme" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                           </font>
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </Text>
                        <BorderPane prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="1130.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-border-radius: 10px;" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                           <center>
                              <GridPane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1200.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="1200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </GridPane>
                           </center>
                           <bottom>
                              <ScrollBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                 <BorderPane.margin>
                                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                                 </BorderPane.margin>
                              </ScrollBar>
                           </bottom>
                        </BorderPane>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

And that did it for me.

And please keep my comment on you question in mind.

**edit:** I needed to remove the link to the controller, otherwise I would not have been able to test it, so don't just copy and paste it back into your application, ok?

Comment: Ah I guess, that is not what you want. I overread it, that you wanted to center the content. Your UI is IMHO overly complicated and should be simplified (or at least decoupled into several FXML files (wich could in turn put together in one file via `fx:includes`. I will probably give it a try to at least simplify it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I would be very grateful if you could show me a way how i can implement this fx:includes. I've nerver heard of that!
With regards,
Timo